# An alternative for Internet Download manager's (IDM) hovering panel in ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, video

In my windows system I regularly uses internet download manager (IDM) for downloading videos, audios and other types of files. The best part of IDM is the hovering download panel shows above the top of a streaming video which can be easily used for downloading  videos. I have installed in my system uGet with flashgot plugin in mozilla but for downloading streaming videos i have to manually click the flashgot plugin and have to select a file from flashgot window.I want to know whether any free download manager available in ubuntu which has IDM like hovering download panel.
[image]

Comment: I've been using savefrom.net for years.

Comment: @JoKeR but it's a web based app; I have used it but IDM is better

Comment: You can try the [1-Click YouTube Video Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1-click-youtube-video-downl/?src=search)

Comment: just curious better in what? with savefrom.net plugin you can download videos audios pictures just about any media from different sources and it's got hovering button also :)

Comment: @Mitch i will install that in my firefox. Whether this add on will work for another video streaming site?

Comment: I use it on YouTube, and other sites as well.

Comment: @JoKeR For small files savefrom.net is good for big files i am doubt full. IDM download is faster, i don't know how idm works but i believe it cuts (for big size) the files and download it simultaneously

Comment: I have no idea I've been downloading FullHD videos from youtube just in a min.:) I guess it rather depends on your internet speed.

Comment: Yes i have a crappy internet speed (approx 256kb/s) so it will be difficult for me to download big files from a website

Comment: this way it be difficult to talk about which is better, as I said the download of FullHD 1080p music video for example with savefrom.net takes me a minute to download.

Comment: @JoKeR sadly you are right, Any way thanks man for the help

Comment: you're welcome:) you can try **Mitch**'s advice and also try savefrom.net plugin it could improved in usability since the last time you used it. Good luck!